# Why draft post show on my home page

Tags: php, wordpress

Unpublished (draft) blog posts are appearing on the homepage when a category is selected But I don't want to show it on my home page.Here is my WP Query

```
 <div class="wm_container wm_row wm_blog_listing">
        <?php
        $wm_home_blog_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
        $wm_home_blog_qry = new WP_Query($wm_home_blog_args);
        if ($wm_home_blog_qry->have_posts()) {
            while ($wm_home_blog_qry->have_posts()) {
                $wm_home_blog_qry->the_post();
                $wm_categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
                $wm_home_term_ID = $wm_categories[0]->term_id;
                $wm_home_blog_bg = get_term_meta($wm_home_term_ID, 'wm_term_color', true);
                ?>
                <article class="wm_col wm_col_3 wm_blog_item"
                         style="background-color: <?php echo $wm_home_blog_bg; ?>">
                    <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        ?>
                        <a class="wm_post_thumbnail_wrapper" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php
                            the_post_thumbnail('wm_recent_issue_cat');
                            ?>
                            <span class="wm_image_overlay">Preview</span>
                        </a>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <a class="wm_post_thumbnail_wrapper" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/255x135?text=No+Image">
                            <span class="wm_image_overlay">Preview</span>
                        </a>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **post_status** (*string / array*) - use post status. Retrieves posts by Post Status. Default value is `'publish'`, but if the user is logged in, `'private'` is added. Public custom statuses are also included by default. And if the query is run in an admin context (administration area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are `'future'`, `'draft'` and `'pending'`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: Its very helpful to me but don't know  why my problem is still :(

Comment: Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: did you tried to dump you `get_post_status` within the loop, just to be sure that displayed posts are `draft` indeed (perhaps you are pulling data from a different DB or something you did not foresee)

Answer (score 3):

Pass Post Status parameter in array

```
$wm_home_blog_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'post_status' => 'publish',  
        );
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I also tried it but not work. Hope so you suggest me different methods soon. ;)

Comment: I think your post not updated properly.update once and then try

Comment: if still not working, add this function in while loop and check status of post. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status